# Xamarin Forms iOS Error: Metadata file '...' could not be found

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I recently updated my Xamarin version on my mac build server and Visual Studio on my windows machine. When I go to build the iOS project, I get an error:

Metadata file '/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/PhantomMqtt.Services.Implementation.dll' could not be found.

That dll should be generated from another project in my solution.

I have tried reinstalling Xamarin on my build server, but that has not helped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try delete all cache from mac, delete bin/obj folders on windows, rebuild project and make sure that PhantomMqtt project built successfuly.

Comment: I tried deleting ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin and related folders, deleted all bin/obj folders on windows, and rebuilt the solution. The build still failed. PhantomMqtt built successfully.

Comment: What is "PhantomMqtt"? Is this your project? Why is it being looked for in the Xamarin.iOS Framework????? Did you update Xamarin on your mac build host to the latest stable version when you updated Xamarin on your PC? Did you update XCode to the latest stable from the app store? Are you on the latest stable version of Xamarin in Visual Studio on Windows (not on VS Preview version)? Also look over this guide on the error MT2001: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors/#MT2001_Could_not_link_assemblies

Comment: Those questions were perfect, it turns out my bindings library had a reference to a different library. I think it was looking for that dll in the framework folder for some reason. I removed the reference.

I'm now getting an error when building that says the linker crashed with a null reference exception. I can turn off linking and the project builds and runs, but that's not very desirable.